# Phalcon $elementMatch

Tags: phalcon, odm

I'm trying to find with $elementMatch condition, but unfortionatly, nothing works correctly:

http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6033/

```
$result = Hotel::findFirst(array(
        '$elementMatch' => array(
            array('sellingCodes' => $this->request->getPost('sellingCode')),
            array("supplierCode" => $this->request->getPost('supplierCode'))
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/odm.html#finding-documents), solution for your problem is probably somewhat close to this:

```
$result = Hotel::findFirst(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'sellingCodes' => $this->request->getPost('sellingCode'),
        'supplierCode' => $this->request->getPost('supplierCode')
    )
));
```